# Change [watson-conversation] to [watson-assistant]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[`[watson-conversation]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/watson-conversation/info) has been rebranded as [`[watson-assistant]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/watson-assistant/info) as is stated in the tag info pages for both.
It currently seems that the `[watson-assistant]` tag is redirected to `[watson-conversation]`, which seems backwards given that conversation is the old branding.
My suggestion is to flip the current synonym, or just completely migrate the old tag.